# InfoWindows doesn't take each info window marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I load the markers from sqlite and I do looping to get data from sqlite the put the marker to each latitude and longitude. It works.
But when I try to get the info window from each marker, it doesnt works. It just take one infowindow.

this is my code:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){

                // mengambil koordinat lokasi ATM

                title = cursor.getString(1).toString();
                __global_endposition = cursor.getString(2).toString();
                alamat = cursor.getString(3).toString();
                String[] exp_endCoordinate = __global_endposition.split(",");
                double lat_endposition = Double.parseDouble(exp_endCoordinate[0]);
                double lng_endposition = Double.parseDouble(exp_endCoordinate[1]);
                LatLng endx = new LatLng(lat_endposition, lng_endposition);

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(endx)
                        .title(title)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
//                mMap.addMarker(options);
                Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
                mapBuilder.include(marker.getPosition());
                addedMarker = true;

                googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), alamat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
```

This is my sqlite record:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10HFe.png)

When I clik to each marker, it only showed "Giant Ekspres, Jl. Urip Sumoharjo, Klitren, Gondokusuman, Kota Yogyakarta" to each marker info windows.

Comment: (1) Do you want to use a toast or would you rather show the additional information in the info window? (2) there is no need to add the `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` on each loop. (3)  what is you map object "mMap"  or `googleMap"?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `onInfoWindowClick` listener per map object.  In your case, you Toast the contents of `alamat` which will always be the last cursor result (column index 3) string.

If you want to display for each marker the `alamat` contents as it appears you intended then the simplest approach is to set the marker's tag field to the contents of `alamat` and then in the listener use the marker's tag field in the toast:

```
alamat = cursor.getString(3).toString();

// ...

MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
    .position(endx)
    .title(title)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
marker.setTag(new String(alamat));

// ...

googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new 
    GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), marker.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

You will soon find you may want to do more than just display the tag string.  So you can either use a more complex object in the tag or use the `marker` id in the `onInfoWindowClick` to access a managed collection of marker data, like a Hashmap.